# Move window with mouse – how to snap to other windows?

Tags: gnome, mouse

When moving a window with the mouse, I find it convenient that the window snaps to other window edges. This used to be the case, but not anymore. Since when I don't really know, but it is quite recent I believe. I'm now on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

The GNOME documentation https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-windows-states.html.en states that holding down <kbd>shift</kbd> should do it. Unfortunately it does not. Anyone?

Comment: For me, it works in Ubuntu 22.04, both in Xorg and Wayland sessions.

Comment: @vanadium that's interesting! I'm on Xorg, and there is no snapping here. Do you use the shift key?

Comment: Yes, hold down shift then start to drag, or start to drag, then holding shift will cause to snap to border or other windows border.

Comment: @vanadium Weird. Strange that my system is so often different.

Comment: I should add that I do not always manage to get the effect. Sometimes, it does not work right away.

Comment: @vanadium that's it. It *sometimes* works here too. That's frustrating.

Comment: @vanadium just a little snag though... When this works, the screen edges get a LOT of attraction force, making it pretty impossible to align windows to other windows – they get glued to the edges instead. Any opinion?